# using Client lib to list Machine Learning models for a dataset with Google Big Query ML Python API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am struggling to find reference on how to use the Python Wrapper to list all the Machine Learning Models associated with a given dataset in BQ

```
client = bigquery.Client(project =project_id)
```

instantiates the client, but then how to run a simple 
`list_models(dataset= dataset_id)` operation?

I can do this via the REST API directly

```
url_bq_ml_list = 'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{}/datasets/{}/models'.format(project_id, dataset_id)
```

but really cannot find how to do this with the python client! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, after searching for quite a bit it seems that it can indeed be done via the python client:

```
models_available = client.list_models(dataset_id)
```

where client:

```
client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
```

where dataset_id is the BQ dataset and the project_id the actual GCP project.

Hope this helps others trying to use Big Query ML